# lotus.domino.Session is not serialized

Tags: apache, serialization, tomcat7, lotus-domino, lotus

I had developed a Java based Lotus Domino Email Client Application. I am saving the lotus.domino.Session object in httpsession.setAttribute for session management.we decided to deploy the application on two different servers and manage load balancing and Session Replication between the two.

Now we are facing issues while Replicating lotus.domino.Session because lotus.domino.Session is not serialized.

Kindly help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you are out of luck.

Domino objects (that is, anything in the lotus.domino package) store a link to a C API object that must be garbage collected to avoid memory leaks.
As a result, if a Domino object is serialized, it will become toxic at the end of the request in which it was stored, because its C object link will have been automatically recycled at the end of that request.

Answer (score 0):

As Leyrer says, it is not possible to serialise any Domino Object as it has a C-API backend component to it which cannot be stored.

Also the Session object was never designed for connection pooling either. So even if you skip the serialisation, you may encounter other issues.

Depending on what it is you are trying to accomplish, you could create your own serialisable object with just the references you need to recreate the session and any other objects.